# Pod fails to mount ConfigMap: `failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition`

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a pod on a v1.18 GKE kubernetes cluster

My pod loop-crashes because it fails to mount its config map:

```
$ kubectl describe pod <pod>

...

Volumes:
  cm-cxf-conf:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      project-cm-cxf-conf
    Optional:  false

...

Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From                     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----                     -------
  Warning  FailedMount             41m                    kubelet                  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "cm-cxf-conf" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition

...
```

However, the config map DOES exist:

```
$ kubectl get configmap project-cm-cxf-conf
project-cm-cxf-conf            1      4h40m
```

What could be the cause of this error? How can I fix it?

## Related threads

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/67770576/3037171
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/62741092/3037171

Comment: Please attach your yaml files. Did you know, you are using deprecated version of kubernetes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the `FailedMount` are just warnings without consequences. When checking `kubelet` logs, there were other logs afterwards stating it finally succeeded mounting the Config Maps, after retrying.

The real reason why my pod was loop-crashing was a Java application-side error (a JAR was missing in the container), in the end nothing to do with kubernetes